# Problems with Remote Push Notification with React Native on Android. Is Ionic or Native Script the better way?

Tags: android, react-native, ionic-framework, nativescript

I develop a cross-platform hybrid app.

I played around with Ionic, Native Script and React Native.

I decided to use React Native.

Now I am integrating Remote Push Notifications and have so many problems with React Native.

Because the development is just at the beginning I think about switching to Ionic or Native Script.

**My problem:**
I want to get an **event with the payload** of the notification **when** the user touches the push notification in the app **and not earlier**.
Then I can handle the event and open a special webview in the app.

Is this scenario possible and easy to implement with **Ionic** or **Native Script**?

Answer (score 2):

***Is it possible with NativeScript?***

Yes, almost everything is possible with NativeScript. We have plugins for most common use cases where you will simply invoke cross platform JavaScript apis. If you find anything missing, you are not lost yet as you can always access any device apis from your project using just JavaScript.

Refer the Firebase plugin [docs](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/MESSAGING.md) to know more on Push Notification.

***In Detail:***

Being a beginner you may be face issues with any technology. Each of these technologies have their own ups and downs, so I would suggest you to understand what those platform offer and choose the best one suits your needs.

Take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rb8smP_xTTY), this guy explains key points about each of these technologies.

You might be aware that *Airbnb* had decided to move away from ReactNative. [Here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/would-airbnb-have-fared-better-with-nativescript-instead-of-react-native) is a blog post form NativeScript that explains how it could be a better choice over ReactNative.

Obviously I would vote for NativeScript considering the following key features,

1. 100% open source & community friendly
2. 100% native UI, performance, and smooth animations
3. 100% direct access to native apis, you don't have to know Java / Objective C but do everything with just JavaScript
4. NativeScript supports frameworks like Angular & Vue so you can reuse your knowledge and share code between your web apps. If you are not familiar with these frameworks, still it got your back by allowing you to build pure JavaScript / TypeScript based apps. I guess there are plans to support other frameworks too, like React but at least not immediately.